# Split address column into three columns, with blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a .xlsx file of customer data that is 20 columns wide and ~16,000 rows long. Column J is `Customer address`, however, each entry in this column is three rows long: `name`, `address line 1` and `address line 2`. Many of the entries have one or more blanks in the various rows.

How do I maintain all of the data in the other columns and break out column J into three separate columns (`name`, `address line 1` and `address line 2`) and allow blanks to stay blank/NA/0?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a title row in Row 1, and there is always 3 rows for every customer, you could try the following:

Insert 3 columns after J
Put in the following formulas in K2:M2 & copy down to the end:

K2: `=IF(MOD(ROW($J1),3)=2,IF(LEN($J1)=0,"",$J1),"")`

L2: `=IF(MOD(ROW($J1),3)=2,IF(LEN($J2)=0,"",$J2),"")`

M2: `=IF(MOD(ROW($J1),3)=2,IF(LEN($J3)=0,"",$J3),"")`

This uses the mod function to break out the data every 3 lines, and it checks if there is a blank, and if so, puts a blank in the cell, otherwise it fills the cell with the data as is.

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach to @Demetri's but far fewer computations:

Assuming the first address starts in Row1, copy your address column twice, from the first copy delete the first cell, from the second the top two cells, each deletion with `Shift cells up`. To delete the repetition, populate a column, staring with Row 1, with:

```
 =MOD(ROW()-1,3)
```

copied down to suit, Filter that column to select `1`s and `2`s and delete those rows. The entire 'filter' column may then be deleted.